# Add Service Reference doesn't appear in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, visual-studio-2010, service-reference

I created a new form project but when I right click on the project I don't see the Add Service Reference button on the menu.

I've been reading something about adding a project guid opening the project file on notepad, but I don't know where to put that on the structure of the xml file.

Does anyone has an idea why this is happening?

Comment: What type of project have you created? Windows Form Application?

Comment: Sure you are not trying to right-click the "solution" rather than the project? Do you have a "References" folder in you solution/project directory?

Comment: Yes it is a Windows Form App
And yes I'm right clicking on the project, not on the solution

Comment: I have the reference folder, and when I right click it, I only get "Add reference"

Comment: Deleted my answer - however, you should probably clarify I. The question that you created a 4.0 application.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try a right-click on the `References` item?

[image]

---

I believe the GUID you are talking to is located here:

[image]

Comment: I did a right click on reference folder, I only get "Add reference".

I read something about "ProjectTypeGuids", not the guid of the project.

Comment: @YeomansLeo to edit the project-type guides, just open the csproj in any editor

Comment: I tried this [link](http://www.christiano.ch/wordpress/2010/02/20/vs-net-add-service-reference-discover-service-does-not-work/), but it didn't work either